# Python tkinter save and change txt file

Tags: python, tkinter, save, txt

My program simply asks creating a new txt file or if it exists, program saves over it.

```
def file_open():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r+', filetypes =[('Txt', '*.txt')])
    if filename is not None:
        t = filename.readlines()
        textentry.delete(0, 'end')
        for item in t:
            textentry.insert(END, item)
```

I am opening an existing txt file into my ListBox.

After I make some adjustments in the text, I am saving it but I can only add new items to txt. When I delete one, my output txt is not updated.

```
def file_save():
    global filename
    if filename == '':
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    if filename is not None:
        f = open(filename, "w")
        for i in textentry.get(0,'end'):
            f.write(i+"\n")
```

**Note: textentry is a ListBox widget**
I tried this code to save but it did not worked. It should simply get the listbox entries to txt when I click save button.

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Try closing the file after writing (`f.close()`).

Comment: Is `textentry` is a `tkinter.Text` widget? Also you know that your `filename` variable contains a the file handle instead of the file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `textentry` is a `tkinter.Listbox` widget you can use this:

```py
def file_open():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt"), ))
    if filename != "":
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            data = file.read()
        textentry.delete(0, "end")
        for line in data.split("\n"):
            textentry.insert("end", line)
```

and

```py
def file_save():
    global filename
    if filename == "":
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt")
    if filename != "":
        with open(filenname, "w") as file:
            file.write("\n".join(textentry.get(0, "end")))
```

The problem with your code is that your `filename` variable contained the handle to the file instead of the file name as a `str`.

Comment: thanks but my textentry is a Listbox widget

Comment: @AliCanÇoban I think I fixed it.

Comment: line 61, in file_save
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper It shows this error @TheLizzard

Comment: Did you fully copy my code? I think you either missed `askopenfilename` or `asksaveasfilename`. Notice the `name` at the end of those function names.

Comment: I have missed that part but when I copied full code, I can not open a file when I click open file button. It gives me _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-mode": must be -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, -multiple, -parent, -title, or -typevariable

Comment: @AliCanÇoban My bad. `filedialog.askopenfilename(mode='r+', filetypes =(("Text files", "*.txt")))` should actually be `filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt"), ))`

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much. I am grateful. Note that in textentry.delete or textentry.get "0.0" gave an error. So, I changed it into "0" and it worked very well. Thank you again.

Comment: @AliCanÇoban No problem. Fixed the `"0.0"` -> `0` in my answer. Forgot to change it when I was converting from `tkinter.Text` to `tkinter.Listbox`